# Can any one explain this go program which uses a method expression

Tags: go

I was going through some go tutorials but I'm not able to understand what method expressions are in go. Can anyone explain this code to me and why/when I should use it?

```
 // Method call with "method expression" syntax
 func main() {
    dog := Dog{}
    b := (*Dog).Bark // method expression 
    b(&dog, 5)
 }
 type Dog struct {}

 // Methods have a receiver, and can also have a pointer
 func (d *Dog) Bark(n int) {
   for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
      fmt.Println("Bark");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) is a function that can be called like a regular function, except that you also pass the object to act on as the first argument. This is because it needs to know which object to use.

Normally, you would just use the following:

```
d := &Dog{}
d.Bark(5)
```

But using a method expression, you can "save" the function, allowing you to pass it to something else. For example, you could choose to use `(*Dog).Bark` or `(*Dog).Sit` as an action, and call it from a helper. eg:

```
func main() {
    var b func(*Dog, int)
    if (shouldBark) {
        b = (*Dog).Bark
    } else {
        b = (*Dog).Sit
    }
    d := Dog{}
    DoAction(b, &d, 3)
}

func DoAction(f func(*Dog, int), d *Dog, n int) {
    f(d, n)
}
```

The specific syntax `(*Dog).Bark` means that you are deriving a function for a method with pointer receiver.

Honestly, these are not very frequently used. I would recommend you get a good grasp of the language first (eg: take the entire [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/)), then explore less used functionality at a later date.

Comment: hi Marc&Sarath thanx for the response, But i can do the same task with following codes.      func DoActionWithoutMethodExpression(f func(int), n int){
         f(n);
    }    func main() {
   shouldBark:=false;
 
    var dog Dog;
    if (shouldBark) {
        DoActionWithoutMethodExpression(dog.Bark,5);
    } else {
                DoActionWithoutMethodExpression(dog.Sit,5);
    }
} So why i use method expression?

Comment: This is different. In my case, `DoAction` doesn't know what the action is, it just runs it. This is useful if you want to pass one of many functions down to helper code.

Comment: In DoAction you passed the pointer to the function of struct Dog, that it needs to call and I am doing the same, then how it is different?Am i missing something?

Comment: You're technically passing the method itself, it's no longer a method expression. There's nothing wrong with either, and people tend to use yours. As I mentioned in my answer, method expressions are not very commonly used. One case would be if the method and the object to act on come from different places (eg: I give the methods expression to a function, and it consumes object to apply it on from a channel). A very rare case.

Comment: ok, I got your point.  This can be the use case.So technically they are two ways of achieving the same thing.

Comment: In the example from your comment above, they would indeed both be possible solutions. There are other cases (different source of the "action" and the object) where only the method receiver would work.

Comment: but "actions" need to have the same signature right?

Comment: Yes, but this is true of callbacks in general: if you pass arguments to them, you need to know what types they are. Not many ways around it.